# Type to store time in C# and corresponding type in T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, time

I would like to know how to **store time in C# and T-SQL**. I know that both of them provide a **DateTime** type but I just need to store a ***time***. For instance:

```
var startTime = 9PM;
var endTime = 10PM;
```

And then **store/retrieve** this values from a database. Thanks in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### C#

Whether to use a `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` type in C# to store `9 PM`  is up to taste. Personally, I'd use `DateTime`, leaving the date component empty, since that's semantically closer to what you want. (A `TimeSpan` is designed to hold *time intervals*, such as "21 hours".)

The documentation supports both options. This is from [the documentation of TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

> The TimeSpan structure can also be used to represent the time of day, but only if the time is unrelated to a particular date.

On the other hand, the MSDN article [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx) mentions the following:

> The DateTime structure is suitable for applications that do the following:
>      * Work with dates only.
>      * Work with times only.
>      [...]

---

### T-SQL

SQL Server has a [`time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) data type.

Comment: thanks for your answer. You are right about the distinction between time and time interval, I already edited my question. I have one last doubt. When I get my time value from the database and I store inside a DateTime object in C# shall I make any kind of cast?

Comment: @Francesco: Thanks. Since this is now no longer necessary, I've removed the comment about time vs. time interval from my answer (and extended it a bit). About the cast: I don't know if one is necessary (i.e. if time maps to TimeSpan or DateTime in ADO.NET).

Comment: I ask about the casting because I use LinqToSql EF and it represents the TSQL time data type as TimeSpan.

Comment: @Francesco: Ah, OK. I don't think a cast will work, but you can convert a TimeSpan to a DateTime like this: `var myDateTime = new DateTime().Add(myTimeSpan)` and vice versa: `var myTimeSpan = myDateTime.TimeOfDay`.

Comment: I know this is old but just for reference, if you use a TIME datatype in TSQL that will map to a TimeSpan datatype in C# using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 2):

In C# there is not a type to hold only a time. There is `TimeSpan`, but it's intended to keep a period of time and not really a component of a `DateTime` (i.e. hours and minutes) only.

Starting with SQL Server 2008 there is a `time` type ([Using Date and Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28SQL.100%29.aspx)) that *does* only store a time component.

EDIT: Misread your question at first. `TimeSpan` is exactly what you're looking for and it can be stored in a `time` type with SQL 2K8.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is the normal way to store a time of day, just ensure it doesn't exceed 24 hours. For example [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) is a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Richard - +1, never knew that

Answer (score 1):

In C# you'd probably want to use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure if you just wanted to store a time *interval*. However, you seem to want to appear to store a start-time and an end-time, which would require storing two values. You could, therefore, use two `TimeSpans` (based on, say, number of minutes from midnight to represent the time) or you could just use two `DateTime` values and throw away the date component.

As has been noted, SQL Server 2008 has a [Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype, but this isn't available in earlier versions which only have `DateTime`. You could also just store an `Int` representing number of minutes past midnight which can be easily converted to a `TimeSpan` (`TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)`).

Answer (score 1):

Timespan in c# is how you manipulate time intervals.  Contrary to what other posters are saying i don't think the Time data type is correct for storing time intervals in SQL, unless you actually want to store the start time and end time and not the time interval (i.e. 1 hour in you example).  It is for storing a time of day, a bit like a DateTime but with no date.  When i want to store a time interval in SQL I just use an int and then have it represent a unit of time appropriate to what I am trying to do (e.g.minutes, seconds, milliseconds etc. )

Comment: The OP has clarified he doesn't want to store a time interval; he appears to want to store two separate time values.